# how to join two table with range of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am using postgresql, and I have those two tables, Sale and Royalty.

*Sale*

| saleId | ItemId | price | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 200 | 2022-08-17 |
| 2 | b | 400 | 2022-08-19 |
| 3 | c | 500 | 2022-09-04 |

*Royalty*

| Id | rate | createdAt | deletedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.25 | 2022-08-10 | 2022-08-20 |
| 2 | 0.15 | 2022-08-20 | 2022-09-01 |
| 3 | 0.20 | 2022-09-01 | null |

I want to join sale and royalty to make result like this.
the point is how to match rate with Sale.createdAt comparing to Royalty's rate period.

*selected Result*

| ItemId | rate*price | Sale.createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 50 (200*0.25) | 2022-08-17 |
| b | 100 (400*0.25) | 2022-08-19 |
| c | 100 (500*0.20) | 2022-09-04 |

I don't want to use between on every royalty since more rows could be added.

I'm considering making Sale-Royalty table to get rate*price easily,

but I wonder if there's a way to solve using join with this condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to utilize postgres' [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) type with its `<@` operator :

```sql
select
    s.*,
    r.rate,
    s.price * rate as value
from sale s
join royalty r on s.createdAt <@ daterange(r.createdAt, r.deletedAt)
;
```

caveats :

- if royalty date ranges overlap, this will multiply the returned rows (a sale having several valid royalty ranges will appear n times)
- replace with an outer (left) join if you need sales even without royalties

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ee459577c0709e30385abb5362f1011e)